# on beamer, show shaded table of contents and incrementally unshade it on same frame

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, pause

I'd like to know how, on the same frame, show first the table of contents all shaded, and then by overlays increasingly revealing (unshading) each line of it.

So far I have this:

```
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections,pausesubsections,subsectionstyle=shaded]
\end{frame}
```

which at the beginning shows first section and hides rest of toc, then incrementally shows subsections shaded and sections unshaded.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a proposal which only works if the table of contents fits in one frame. The idea is to first draw a "faded" table of contents, and then put a second one on top that gets successively uncovered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.85\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}[default][50] 
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
\end{minipage}};
\node at (0,0) {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\tableofcontents[pausesections,pausesubsections]
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.85\textheight}

\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.85\textheight}

\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{Yet another subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Yet another frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.85\textheight}

\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine. However: why can't you use `\smash` on `\tableofcontents`? I just tried and got an error. `tikz` seems like a big package to achieve the overlap here.

Comment: @JesseKnight Yes, loading Ti*k*Z *only* for this is an overkill. However, all of my attempts avoiding this so far have lead to unsatisfactory results.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, though it requires including a few packages.

We will create the table of contents one line at a time, using `parts`, since `\tableofcontents[part=1]` will create the TOC for some specified part of the document. This will allow us to use the [overlay specifications](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/20/beamer-series-pt4.html) features in `beamer` to unshade the lines one-at-a-time.

To separate the lines by section and subsection, we first prepend an empty `\part{}` call to both `\section` and `\subsection` commands using the `\pretocmd` command from the package `etoolbox`:

```
\pretocmd{\section}{\part{}}{}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\part{}}{}{}{}
```

Next, we count the number of `parts` which are created in the document using the `totvalue` command from the `totcount` package:

```
\regtotcounter{part} % <- preamble
...
\totvalue{part} % <- the total number
```

Finally, we use the `\foreach` command from the `tikz` package to loop through all the `parts`, and print the TOC for just this element, with an `\uncover` specification:

```
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \foreach\i in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}%
    {\uncover<\i->{\tableofcontents[part=\i,subsectionstyle=shaded]}}
\end{frame}
```

Personally, I think the double shading of `subsections` is too hard to see, but you can play around with it.

An entire [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{part}
\pretocmd{\section}{\part{}}{}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\part{}}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \foreach\i in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}%
    {\uncover<\i->{\tableofcontents[part=\i,subsectionstyle=shaded]}}
\end{frame}

\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Sec 1.1}
\subsection{Sec 1.2}
\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{Sec 1.1}
\subsection{Sec 1.2}
\begin{frame}
dummy
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the all-shaded toc into a separate frame and decrease the framenumber to make them look like one frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
          \tableofcontents[
            currentsection
          ]
    \end{frame} 
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
          \tableofcontents[
            pausesections,
            pausesubsections,
          ]
    \end{frame}
}

\section{sec1}
\subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\subsection{sub2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{sec2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```